# Fantasy book series (with dragons) about a boy who escapes from a tower

Tags: story-identification, dragons

I'm looking for a book series that I started reading in 2006. The story is about a young boy who lives in a tower of sorts. He somehow manages to escape from his home.

I don't remember much. I think he has a sister he got away from? In one episode he walks through a tunnel and finds a mighty chained dragon.

The cover was something very simple, just text and a golden dragon symbol, I think.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=dragon+book+cover&espv=2&biw=1360&bih=599&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIkJPmuMqXxwIVA48NCh02tASL#tbs=ic:specific%2Cisc:red&tbm=isch&q=dragon+fantasy+book+cover&imgrc=Secu5rugHLXBFM%3A

Comment: Thank you :) sadly no, a bit darker with a pretty serious theme